# installing gnuplot 4.6.3 on mac OS 10.8

Tags: macos, lua, makefile, gnuplot

I am trying to install gnuplot 4.6.3 on my new Macbook Pro running OS 10.8.3.

I installed Xcode 4.6.2, and I have been able to compile some programs, so I think it is ok. There is also an issue with readlines on Mac and I followed the steps here to resolve that: http://bhou.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/how-to-install-gnuplot-in-mac-os-x-lion/

However, I am still having trouble installing gnuplot. When I cd into the gnuplot directory and type

```
./configure --with-read-line=/Path_to_readline/readline-6.2
```

I get this warning:

```
Could not find support for lua using pkg-config.
```

I went and installed LUA, and I can call it from the terminal prompt regardless of the directory I am in (i.e. it's in my PATH), so I think LUA is there, but for some reason it's not being recognized. The relevant lines from the ./config output say this:

```
checking for LUA... no
checking for LUA... no
configure: WARNING: Could not find support for lua using pkg-config.
checking for library containing luaL_openlibs... -llua
checking lua.h usability... yes
checking lua.h presence... yes
checking for lua.h... yes
```

Since I can't think of anything else to try, I just went ahead and tried:

```
make
```

I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [gnuplot] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I think this is a separate problem, but I'm also at a loss about how to deal with this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not an answer, but if all you want is to get get gnuplot running, check out [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/). It's an `apt`-style package manager for OS X that works quite well and manages dependencies between packages automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I had tried Macports and Homebrew before posting this and had trouble with those because I was somehow missing the program `install`, even though I had the latest version of Xcode and command line tools. Once I got `install` I could install gnuplot no problem using a package manager.

Comment: If missing install then you have another problem I would reinstall Xcode command line tools - You don't know what else is missing or broken